# Re-arrange row order query only works when number of rows is odd

Tags: mysql

I have a table with rows from a database that I want to move up or down one by one.

My current query works perfect when the total number of rows is odd, but when there is an even amount, none of the queries work.

For example, I have a table called questions and a column called question_order to change positions.  For question 2, I have this query:

Move Up Button:

```
UPDATE questions
      SET    `question_order`=(CASE `question_order` WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
      WHERE  `question_order`=1 OR `question_order`=2
```

Move Down Button:

```
UPDATE questions
      SET    `question_order`=(CASE `question_order` WHEN 2 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END)
      WHERE  `question_order`=2 OR `question_order`=3
```

When I have an odd number of rows, like 5 questions in the table, it works.

If I have an even number, like 6 questions, no queries work at all.

Does anyone know why my query only works when I have an odd amount of rows?

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: Hi... I got my code working.  The query is fine, the problem was in my php code... There was a loop that was causing this issue.  I moved these queries outside the loop and it works fine now.  Thanks.